# Variable + 1 in for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a block of text with the format 'abc,def,ghi,jkl, etc'
I need to turn each 3-digit bit into something else, in this case a letter. However, using a for loop, I can't find a way of looking beyond the current character. I'm looking for something a little like this:

```
for char in message[::4]:
   if char == 'a':
      if char(+1) == 'b':
         newmessage += 1
```

I'd prefer to use a for loop, but if there's no way of doing it, a while loop would be fine too.

Comment: look at `message.split(',')`

Comment: Why not just use `for chunk in message.split(','):`?

Comment: @BaronPaprika - Please make sure to choose the correct answer when present or else you get the different flavors but the same thing down below. I call these people vultures trying to grab easy points

Answer (score 1):

```
for word in message.split(","):
    for ind, char in enumerate(word[:-1], 1):
        if char == 'a' and word[ind] == "b":
            newmessage += 1
```

If you want the sum use a generator expression with sum:

```
new_message = sum(char == 'a' and word[ind] == "b" for word in message.split(",")
                  for ind, char in enumerate(word[:-1], 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in message.split(','):
    if x == "abc":
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, char in enumerate(message[::4]):
    if char == 'a':
        if message[index + 1] == 'b':
            newmessage += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, char in enumerate(message[::4]):
    if char == 'a':
        if message[i * 4 + 1] == 'b':
            newmessage += 1
```